# How to calling function async await every one second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I have problem with async function with standard `setInterval`. If used `setInterval` I will get:

> pageHook.js:6262 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 503

Then I have tried to use:

```js
async function GetAccount() {
  var contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contractAddress);
  console.log("3");
}

const jobs = []
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (jobs.length == 10) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  let job = Promise.resolve('new job created');
  jobs.push(job);
  console.log('job created');

  GetAccount();
}, 1000);
```

The above function is not calling function `GetAccount()`

Comment: A 503 error means that the server you're calling is either being flooded with requests and is overloaded, or has blocked you as it believes you're trying to DDOS the system. This is the ***exact*** reason why making AJAX requests in an interval/loop is a terrible idea. Without knowing your situation, or exactly what you're trying to achieve, we cannot advise on an alternative method.

Comment: "*The above function is not calling function `GetAccount()`*" - that's not what the error message says.